# No option selected in drop down menu

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have an application [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/example.php)

Now lets say in my database it looks like this:

Course Table:

```
CourseId CourseNo CourseName          Duration
1        INFO101  ICT                 3/4
2        INFO102  Computing           2/3
3        INFO103  Computing Science   3
```

In the course dropdown menu it displays the list of couses from the database as so:

```
Please Select
INFO101-ICT 
INFO102-Computing
INFO103-Computing Science
```

In the duration dropdown menu it displays a duration options which are below:

```
Please Select
1
1/2
2
2/3
3
3/4
4
4/5
5
5/6
6
6/7
7
7/8
8
8/9
9
9/10
10
```

Now what is suppose to happen in the applcation is that when you select a course from the drop down menu, then it should select the duartion from the duration drop down menu which matches the duration which belongs to the course in the database.

So for example if I select course `INFO101-ICT` from the coure drop down menu, then it should automatically select duration `3/4` in the duration drop down menu.

But in the application it is not doing this, when I select a course, it is just select a blank option in the duration drop down menu.

My question is how can I get the correct duration selected in the duration drop down menu depending on the course selected from the course drop down menu?

Below is the full code for the application:

```
     <?php

        // connect to the database
        include('connect.php');


        /* check connection */
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            die();
        }

        ?>

        <h1>EDIT COURSE</h1>

        <?php

        $min_year     = 1;
        $max_year     = 10;
        $years        = range($min_year, $max_year); // returns array with numeric values of 1900 - 2012
        $durationHTML = '';
        $durationHTML .= '<select name="duration" id="newDuration">' . PHP_EOL;
        $durationHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>' . PHP_EOL;

        foreach ($years as $year) {
            $durationHTML .= "<option>$year</option>" . PHP_EOL;
            if ($year != $max_year) {
                $nextYear = $year + 1;
                $durationHTML .= "<option>$year/$nextYear</option>" . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
        $durationHTML .= '</select>';

        $newCourseNo = (isset($_POST['CourseNoNew'])) ? $_POST['CourseNoNew'] : '';

        $coursequery = "
        SELECT CourseId, CourseNo, CourseName, Duration
        FROM Course
        ORDER BY CourseNo
        ";

        $courseqrystmt = $mysqli->prepare($coursequery);
        // You only need to call bind_param once

        $courseqrystmt->execute();

        $courseqrystmt->bind_result($dbCourseId, $dbCourseNo, $dbCourseName, $dbDuration);

        $courseqrystmt->store_result();

        $coursenum = $courseqrystmt->num_rows();

        $courseHTML = '';

        $courseHTML = '<select name="courses" id="coursesDrop">' . PHP_EOL;
        $courseHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>' . PHP_EOL;

        $courseInfo = array();

        while ($courseqrystmt->fetch()) {
            $courseHTML .= sprintf("<option value='%s'>%s - %s</option>", $dbCourseId, $dbCourseNo, $dbCourseName) . PHP_EOL;

            $courseData               = array();
            $courseData["CourseId"]   = $dbCourseId;
            $courseData["CourseNo"]   = $dbCourseNo;
            $courseData["CourseName"] = $dbCourseName;
            $courseData["Duration"]   = $dbDuration;

            array_push($courseInfo, $courseData);
        }


        $courseHTML .= '</select>';


        $courseform = "
        <form action='" . htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "' method='post' id='courseForm'>
        <p><strong>Course:</strong> {$courseHTML} </p>   
        </form>";

        echo $courseform;



        $editcourse = "
        <form id='updateCourseForm'>

        <p><strong>New Course Details:</strong></p>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Duration (Years):</th> 
        <td id='data'>{$durationHTML}</td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        </form>
        ";

        echo $editcourse;

        ?>

        < script type = "text/javascript" > 
$(document).ready(function() {

    var courseinfo = '<?php echo json_encode($courseInfo);?>';

    $('#coursesDrop').change(function() {

        var courseId = $(this).val(),
        coursedata;

        for (var i = 0, l = courseinfo.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (courseinfo[i].CourseId == courseId) {
                coursedata = courseinfo[i];
            }
        }

        var index = $('#newDuration option[value="' + courseinfo.Duration +  '"]').attr('selected','selected');
        alert(courseinfo.Duration);

    });
});
         < /script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is this:

```
if (courseinfo[i].courseId = courseId) {
    coursedata = courseinfo[i];
}
```

Should be this:

```
if (courseinfo[i].courseId == courseId) {
    coursedata = courseinfo[i];
}
```

You want the comparison operator `==` rather than `=`.

Another problem is the following is a literal string rather than calling the php function:

```
var courseinfo = '<?php=json_encode($courseInfo);?>';
```

View the page source and you will see that `courseinfo` has a value of `'<?php=json_encode($courseInfo);?>'` rather than the output of `json_encode($courseInfo)`. You need to fix this up to output the php.

**Edit 2**

There are few more problems in your code. Here is the code that will work.

**Javascript**

```
var courseinfo = [{"CourseId":1,"CourseNo":"INFO101","CourseName":"Bsc Information Communication Technology","Duration":"3\/4"},{"CourseId":2,"CourseNo":"INFO102","CourseName":"Bsc Computing","Duration":"3\/4"},{"CourseId":8,"CourseNo":"INFO103","CourseName":"Business and Finance","Duration":"3"},{"CourseId":7,"CourseNo":"INFO104","CourseName":"English","Duration":"3\/4"},{"CourseId":9,"CourseNo":"INFO105","CourseName":"Mathematics","Duration":"3\/4"},{"CourseId":10,"CourseNo":"INFO106","CourseName":"Law","Duration":"3"}];

$('#coursesDrop').change(function() {

    var courseId = $(this).val(),
        coursedata, i;

    for (i = 0, l = courseinfo.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (courseinfo[i].CourseId == courseId) {
            coursedata = courseinfo[i];
        }
    }

    var index = $('#newDuration').val(coursedata.Duration);

});​
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dd83A/1/)**

Here were the problems.

You need to remove the single quote around your `courseinfo` array:

```
var courseinfo = [...];
```

Your if statement needs the correct case for it's variable `courseinfo` `CourseId`. In the array is `CourseId` so this is what it needs to be in the `if` comparison:

```
if (courseinfo[i].CourseId == courseId) {
    ...
}
```

Use `coursedata.Duration` to set the `#newDuration` `val`.

```
var index = $('#newDuration').val(coursedata.Duration);
```

Comment: Hi, I changed the operater from = to == but it is still doing same thing. I updated code and app to include the operator change

Comment: I managed to output the `json_encode($courseInfo)` but still not working. I have updated application and code. It doesn't display an empty option in duration output when the user selects a course but it just doesn't change option, it still displays the 'Please Select' option

Comment: Now I did an `alert(courseinfo.Duration);` and after I select a course, it displays in the alert `undefined` so this is where the problem is. Do you know what I need to change?

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you have

```
if (courseinfo[i].courseId = courseId) {
  coursedata = courseinfo[i];
}
```

Your if is not good, it should be

```
if (courseinfo[i].courseId == courseId) {
  coursedata = courseinfo[i];
}
```

Then, to select, you should use

```
$('#newDuration option[value="' + courseData.Duration +  "]').attr("selected","selected");
```

You need to remove $('#newDuration')[0].selectedIndex = index;. And your comparison in the for loop is with courseId while your object contains CourseId

Comment: Hi, I changed the operater from = to == but it is still doing same thing. I updated code and app to include the operator change

Comment: I tried to change the line to `        var index = $('#newDuration option[value="' + courseinfo.Duration +  '"]').attr('selected','selected');
` like you mentioned and even though it doesn't select a blank option after selecting a course, it doesn't change selection, it still selects `Please Select` option

Comment: You need to remove `$('#newDuration')[0].selectedIndex = index;`. And your comparison is with `courseId` while your object contains `CourseId`

Comment: Now I did an `alert(courseinfo.Duration);` and after I select a course, it displays in the alert `undefined` so this is where the problem is. Do you know what I need to change?

Comment: @user1861818 see my previous comment.

Comment: I removed the line of code and changed it to CourseId but still no change. Application updated and code updated

Comment: Problem has been solved by 3dgoo. I have upvoted your answer still

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#newDuration').val(courseData.Duration);
```

insted of

```
var index = $('#newDuration option[value="' + courseData.Duration +'"]').index('#newDuration option');
$('#newDuration')[0].selectedIndex = index;
```

**--- Edit ---**

If `courseinfo` is a JsonString you should change your code like this:

```
var courseinfoJson = '<?php=json_encode($courseInfo);?>';
var courseinfo = $.parseJSON(courseinfoJson);

 $('#coursesDrop').change(function() {
    var courseId = $(this).val();
    var coursedata;

    for (var i = 0, i = courseinfo.length; i++) {
        if (courseinfo[i]['CourseId'] == courseId) {
            coursedata = courseinfo[i];
        }
    }

    $('#newDuration').val(courseData['Duration']);
}
```

**--- Edit ---**

Comment: Can you check (by print or console) the value of `courseData.Duration` and see if it matches any of the values in   `$('#newDuration')`

Comment: I changed the line of code as you mentioned like you mentioned and even though it doesn't select a blank option in the duration drop down menu after selecting a course, it doesn't change selection, it still selects Please Select option

Comment: Ok if I look at view page source for `var courseinfo = '<?php echo json_encode($courseInfo);?>';`, then it outputs 
    `var courseinfo = '[{"CourseId":1,"CourseNo":"INFO101","CourseName":"ICT","Duration":"3\/4"},{"CourseId":2,"CourseNo":"INFO102","CourseName":"Computing","Duration":"2\/3"}.....`

Comment: Now I did an `alert(courseinfo.Duration);` and after I select a course, it displays in the alert `undefined` so this is where the problem is. Do you know what I need to change?

Comment: Now i get it! courseinfo is a json string, so you need to parse it to make it an jquery object (or array of objects in your case) `$.parseJSON(courseinfo);`

Comment: Problem has been solved by 3dgoo. I have upvoted your answer still